# Detatching a scrolling nav bar from the rest of the scrolling site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a twitter bootstrap parallax template (purchased) - specifically regarding the nav bar, the way it currently works is when you click a nav menu item, the nav bar scrolls up with the rest of the site, then reappears further down the page and remains fixed at the top. What I'd like is for it to **not** scroll up in the first instance, and just remain fixed at the top the whole time.

This is the site in testing:

http://realestatemediafactory.com/test/

One thing I did try was wrapping the entire nav bar in the code below:

```
<div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="160">
```

But the result was messy, and I figured it better to switch off/modify the code causing the scroll rather than try to cancel it out with more code...

Unsure whether this is controlled by css or jquery, so have not copied any of my code here... whatever's needed I'm happy to paste here.

Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand correctly your question and if this will help you
With firebug I tried to edit the css code
Search in your css code this selector and try to modify it so

```
 .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-inner, .navbar-static-top .navbar-inner {
    background: url("../img/line_bg.png") repeat scroll left top rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-bottom: medium none;
    box-shadow: none;
    filter: none;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    transition: padding 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1030;
}
```

With this modification, the navigation bar should always remain fixed at the top
Again: i've only tried with firebug so I'm not sure of the result
If this solution does not suit your needs, i apologize for making you lose time.

Answer (score 0):

Mate thank you very much for your help - I did try that and it solved the problem for the most part, but there was still a positioning issue. I actually found there were two css classes for the header, one fixed and one scrolling, which were controlled by a script which switched between them depending on the position of the page. I turned off the script and that has solved the problem. The script I switched off is below. Thanks again for your help!

```
<script>
    var navbar = jQuery('#navbartop');
    var navbartop = jQuery('#topnavbar');
        jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
            if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 640) {

                navbar.addClass("navbar-scroll");
                navbartop.removeClass("navbar-static-top");
                navbartop.addClass("navbar-fixed-top");

            } else {
                navbar.removeClass("navbar-scroll");
                navbartop.removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");
                navbartop.addClass("navbar-static-top");
            }
        });
    </script>
```